# Foreach Loop to Display 2 column with different row

Tags: php

I have a query result($wp_query) that getting the latest 5 post, which I want to display in 2 different column (bootstrap grid / column).

The first column will display the first 3 record out of 5, as slider which i used Slippry slider ([Slippry Slider](http://slippry.com/)).

While the second column will display the balance 2 record in individual row, which means 1 record in 1 row.

Im not sure how to do for the second column but I did manage to get the slider, though its showing all 5 record as slider.

Below is my code (its from wordpress functions.php, which i will put in one of my blog page as shortcode)

Any hint will be much appreciated.

```
function latest_highlights_func($args){
global $wp_query;
        $args = array(
        'tag__in' => '24', //must use tag id for this field
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => '5'
        );

$posts = get_posts($args);
//echo"fiz==". count($posts);
//$output = "<div class='vc_col-md-8'>";
$output = "";

$counter = 1;
//
    foreach ($posts as $_post) {
        $counter++; 

        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID ) ) {

            if( $counter == 3 ){
                $output .= "<div class='vc_col-md-8'>";
                $output .= "<ul id='slippry-demo'><li>";
            }

            $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $_post->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( $_post->post_title ) . '">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $_post->ID, 'full' , array('alt'=> esc_attr( $_post->post_title )) ).'
                            </a>';
            if($counter < 4){               
                $output .= "</li></ul></div><div class='vc_col-md-4'>";
            }

            if($counter < 6){
                $output .= "</div>";            
            }
        }   

    }

echo $output;   

    }
    add_shortcode("latest_highlights", "latest_highlights_func");
```

Cheers

Comment: just a view hints: at the line `$counter < 4` you're adding `</ul></div>` but you never opened a `<ul>` or `<div>` tag. Also you're closing a `</li>` but you never open it with `<li>`

Comment: Noted on the missing `<li>`. But i already open the `<div>` in the line whre i put my condition for first 3 record. `if( $counter == 3 ){`. Still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable as a counter in for each loop and check it with the if statement, once counter reach to 3 change the structure of html code for column 2.

Comment: hi saquib, i've edit the code as above but still no success.=(